# WCF Named Pipe Binding - Communication Exception

Tags: c#, wcf, named-pipes

I have a WCF named pipe binding that works 99% of the time.  I'm having trouble when sending large messages.  Specifically, a string greater than 65535 in length.

The actual exception message is:

> The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by
>   a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal
>   server error.

Normally, I would expect an exception message about MaxMessageLength or something similar.

Below, this is the function that I'm using to open my pipe.  As you can see, I believe I'm setting the max message size correctly.

```
    private void OpenPipe()
    {
        try
        {
            var pipeBinding = new NetNamedPipeBinding();
            pipeBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;                
            pipeBinding.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
            pipeBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue;                                

            pipeBinding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
            pipeBinding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
            pipeBinding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
            pipeBinding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);                

            pipeFactory =
new DuplexChannelFactory<ITsmNPContracts>(this, pipeBinding, new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/TsmPipe"));

            pipeFactory.Closed += pipeFactory_Closed;
            serviceClient = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
            isChannelOpen = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //channel not open
            lastError = e;
        }
    }
```

This seems like a pretty poor exception message and does not really give me any hints to what the problem is.  Any ideas?  Thanks

**-EDIT**  The particular function I'm calling instantly fails as well.  So I don't believe that I'm hitting my send / receive timeouts.

Comment: why dont you implement partial sending of large data?

Comment: and here is an explanation why you shouldn send large messages https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a3ee3c46-9afc-4a6a-b9d2-26b8230942d9/named-pipe-max-message-size?forum=netfxnetcom

Comment: @SebastianL I'll certainly give it a shot.  Might be a little difficult because I have a two-way binding.